# Fetch data from ZOHO CREATOR API with python using requests library

Tags: python, html, python-requests, zoho

I'm trying to fetch data from the [zoho creator API](https://www.zoho.com/creator/help/api/rest-api/rest-api-view-records-in-view.html) using Python 3 with Requests. Even though I´ve used python for some casual work and data crunshing, I dont have any idea about http requests. Can anyone help me translating the following html code into an equivalent python code using requests?

```
<form method="GET" action="https://creator.zoho.com/api/xml/sample/view/Employee_View">
<input type="hidden" name ="authtoken" value="************">
<input type="hidden" name ="zc_ownername" value="********">
<input type="hidden" name="criteria" value='(PacienteSL=="Abilio Alfredo Finotti")'>
<input type="hidden" name ="scope" id="scope" value="creatorapi">
<input type="submit" value="View Records">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had some success using requests with urllib to make these kind of calls - something like the below should translate the above html.

```
import requests
import urllib

param = urllib.parse.urlencode({"authtoken":"token_here", 
  "scope":"creatorapi",
  "zc_ownername":"owner_here",
  "criteria":'(PacienteSL=="Abilio Alfredo Finotti")'})

url = "https://creator.zoho.com/api/xml/{0}/view/{1}/{2}".format("sample", "Employee_View", param)

requests.get(url).content
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for urllib, requests takes care of it for you:

```py
import requests


url = "https://creator.zoho.com/api/xml/sample/view/Employee_View/"
params = {
    "authtoken": "***",
    "scope": "creatorapi",
    "zc_ownername": "***",
    "criteria": "(PacienteSL==\"Abilio Alfredo Finotti\")"
}

requests.get(url, params=params).content
```